# How to put none price products at the end of the list with sorting lowest price to highest

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to sorting product based on price, lowest to highest,But how Can I put none price products at the end of  the result?

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'=>'15',
     'post_status'    => 'publish',
     'orderby' =>'meta_value_num',
     'meta_key' => '_price',
     'order' => 'ASC',
      'tax_query'      => $tax_query,
     
);
```

Comment: Woocommerce or custom implementation?

Comment: it's Woocommerce